# Prove that the following set is countable.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, elementary-set-theory

In the Munkres proof of countable product of second countable spaces is second countable, he stated that the set $F=\{\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}U_i\}$ where $U_i=B_i$, where $B_i\in\mathcal{B_i}$ for finitely many $i$'s and $\mathcal{B_i}$ is a set of countable basis. And $U_i = X_i$ for the rest, where $X_i$ is a second countable space.

Intuitively, I understand the cardinality of $F$ should be countable. But I have trouble rigorously showing it. Any ideas?

Comment: But a countable cartesian product of finite elements is uncountable...

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set $\mathbb{N}^{< \omega}$ of *finite* subsets of $\mathbb{N}$:

$\mathbb{N}^{< \omega}$ is countable: there are $\aleph_0$ sets of size 1 (all sets $\{n\}$, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$, also $\aleph_0$ many two point sets (as this is at most the size of $\mathbb{N}^2$ which is $\aleph_0$ again), and similarly for all $k$, $\aleph_0$ many sets of size $k$ (as $|\mathbb{N}^k| = |\mathbb{N}| = \aleph_0$).
And $$\mathbb{N}^{< \omega} = \cup_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \{A \subseteq \mathbb{N}: |A| = k\}$$ is then a countable union of countable sets so also countable.

Now for every finite set $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, we consider:

$$\mathcal{B}_A = \{\prod_n U_n \subseteq \prod_n X_n: (\forall n \in A: U_n \in \mathcal{B}_n) \land (\forall n \notin A: U_n = X)\}$$ which is a subfamily of the base from the countable bases $\mathcal{B}_n$ of $X_n$, and which is countable (for this fixed $A$) because we have countably many choices for each coordinate of $A$ and none outside it, so $|\mathcal{B}_A| =( \aleph_0)^{|A|} = \aleph_0$ as $A$ is finite.

But then $\mathcal{B} = \bigcup_{A \in \mathbb{N}^{< \omega}} \mathcal{B}_A$ is also a countable union of countable sets, hence countable. (You use $F$ for this set)

Answer (score 0):

There are countably many sets for which U1 /= X.
There are countably many sets for which U1 /= X and U2 /= X.
...
There are countably many sets for which U1,.. Uj /= X.
...
Add the cardinality of all those sets to get countable x countable many sets which, of course, is countable.